# UIApplication not opening url

Tags: swift, url, uigesturerecognizer, uiapplication

I am grabbing the URL from a struct and sending it to a `UITapGesture`, and I tried printing it(it prints URL), but it doesn't want to actually open the URL.

```
@objc func getUrl(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    guard  let url = self.rssUrl else { return }
    print(url)
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Grabbing an URL here

```
var rssUrl: URL?

var item: RSSItem! {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        //other code

        let store_Article = Article(dict: ["text": sum, "rssUrl": rssLink])
        storedArticle.append(store_Article)

        let data = dataUrl.init(articleUrl: store_Article).someUrl

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            //other code
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

> it prints: http:/www.instyle.com/news/rihanna-30th-birthday-party -- file:///

for an example

Comment: What you get in  print(url)?

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya see edit

Comment: How many accounts do you have now in the last couple of days? This is at least three. Why?

Comment: @rmaddy just 3 it keeps banning me from asking questions even after a week

Comment: @rmaddy I had an account that was doing well, then all of a sudden stack banned me from asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this
**EDIT**

```
@objc func getUrl(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    guard let url = URL(string: YOUR_URL_STRING) else {
        return //be safe
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work it gives an error type, the URL is type URL

Comment: I checked its working fine. Please check EDIT answer

Comment: Yw! Happy coding!!